# How to set the DisplayMemberPath for explicitly implemented interface?

Tags: c#, wpf

My `User` class implements the `IUser` interface **explicitly**. This class is `internal`, but the interface is `public`. In my other assembly I get the `IEnumerable<IUser>` data and try to set it as data source for my WPF element.

I have the problem with the `DisplayMemberPath` property using.

This is my interface:

```
public interface IUser {

    string Name { get; set; }

    string MiddleName { get; set; }

    string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `User` class:

```
internal class User : IUser {

    public User(string name, string middleName, string surname) {

        IUser user = (IUser)this;

        user.Name = name;
        user.MiddleName = middleName;
        user.Surname = surname;
    }

    string name;

    string IUser.Name {
        get {
            return name;
        }

        set {
            if (IsValidName(value)) {

                name = value?.Trim();
            }
            else {
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(IUser.Name));
            }
        }
    }

    private bool IsValidName(string value) {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {

            return false;
        }

        string tmp = value.Trim();

        if (tmp.All(n => char.IsLetter(n))) {

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    string middleName;

    string IUser.MiddleName {
        get {
            return middleName;
        }

        set {
            if (IsValidName(value)) {

                middleName = value?.Trim();
            }
            else {
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(IUser.MiddleName));
            }
        }
    }

    string surname;

    string IUser.Surname {
        get {
            return surname;
        }

        set {
            if (IsValidName(value)) {

                surname = value?.Trim();
            }
            else {
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(IUser.Surname));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code of `IUser` using:

```
IFactory factory = Factory.Current;
IProjectDataProvider provider = factory.CreateProjectDataProvider()
    ;

// Get data sources
IEnumerable<IUser> users = provider.GetProjectMainArchitects();

Window win = new Window();
ComboBox cbox = new ComboBox();
cbox.Width = 200;
cbox.Height = 20;
cbox.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
cbox.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
win.Content = cbox;

Binding bind = new Binding();
bind.Source = users;

cbox.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, bind);
// cbox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";

Application app = new Application();
app.Run(win);
```

This is the result:

[image]

But If I uncomment the `// cbox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";` code row then I get such result:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I guess you have tried making the User class public, haven't you? Or is it in the same assembly like your view?

Comment: The `User` class are to be `internal` and hi is. My second code example is located in other assembly. I do it in order that work was performed strictly through interfaces.

Comment: That would explain why you can't see anything in your second example. Cause the other assembly does not have access to your User class and its properties.

Comment: I give `IEnumerable <iuser>` as data source. `IUser` instances are available for using because this interface is declared as `public`.

Comment: Easy way to fix this is to make `Name` public (`User` class can still be internal in this case). All access to properties is done via reflection, so whether you pass class or interface instance is irrelevant in this case. WPF will (basically) do GetType().GetProperty("Name").

Comment: `Name` is public, because the interface is public.

Comment: If `Name` is public then I cannot reproduce your issue. With code you provided it works fine when Name is public (but does not work if it's internal).

Comment: Yes, the interface is public but you can't get access to your User properties because they are internal...

Comment: Ah sorry, in my example I had `public Name {get;set;}` and also has explicit interface implementation `string IUser.Name
        {
            get { return this.Name; }
            set { this.Name = value; }
        }`, that is why it works. With just explicit implementation it will not work, because as I said all is done via reflection, and WPF will not find your property (that interface itself is public does not matter).

Comment: I don't need to get the property of `User` internal class. I need to get the property of `IUser` public interface which is implemented by `User` explicitly.

Comment: I added code of my `User` class to this theme.

Comment: Since you cannot do that with your implementation, maybe time to think why you implement that interface explicitly at all.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `DisplayMemberPath` property doesn't work form explicitly implemented properties.

You should define an `ItemTemplate` with a `TextBlock` that explicitly binds to the explicitly implemented property.

This is an easy thing to do in XAML:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1;assembly=WpfApplication1">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding (local:IUser.Name)}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

If you want to do it programmatically for some reason you could use the `XamlReader.Parse` to create the `DataTemplate`:

```
cbox.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, bind);

cbox.ItemTemplate = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse("<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:local=\"clr-namespace:WpfApplication1;assembly=WpfApplication1\"><TextBlock Text=\"{Binding (local:IUser.Name)}\" /></DataTemplate>") as DataTemplate;
this.Content = cbox;
```

Don't forget to replace "WpfApplication1" with the actual name of the namespace and the assembly in which the `IUser` interface is defined.

Comment: I try to use it: `cbox.ItemTemplate = XamlReader.Parse("<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:local=\"clr-namespace:PikGroup.RobotIRA.Core;assembly=Core\"><TextBlock Text=\"{Binding (local:IUser.Name)}\" /></DataTemplate>") as DataTemplate;` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Are you getting an exception or what happens? Is your assembly really named "Core"?

Comment: It means that I get the same invalid result as I showed on my second screen. No, I haven't an exception. Yes, its name is `Core.dll`.

Comment: So what do you see in the ComboBox when you set the ItemTemplate property? Try to set the Text property of the TextBlock in the XAML to a static string for testing purposes. If you don't see this text, then you haven't applied the ItemTemplate. Please update your question with a full repo.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said you have to make at least your Name property public to access it from another assembly. Maybe this link will help you to understand the issue: [Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173121.aspx)

Short form: you can access your interface in another assembly but not the properties of the explicit type when it's in another assembly and internal.

And because your bindings need public access you can't see the Name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is not the visibility of the class, but the fact that you have implemented your interface explicitly. An explicit implementation is equivalent to it being private from the point of view of visibility (actually it is worse than that because you can only call it from within the class itself via an explicit cast).

Bindings can only see public members, so it can't see the explicitly implemented members of the class. (the omission of the public modifier is a hint!)

The only reason you usually need to implement something explicitly is due to a name clash.

Try this to see the problem:

Code behind:

```
public interface IBlah
{
    string ExplicitMember { get; set; }
    string Member { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : IBlah
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    string IBlah.ExplicitMember { get; set; } = "Hidden";

    public string Member { get; set; } = "Visible";
}
```

And this in the XAML:

```
<Window
    x:Class="ExplicitBind.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExplicitBind"
    Height="350"
    Width="525"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ExplicitMember}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Member}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Agree with everything you said, except there are other reasons to implement explicitly. Perhaps you want to hide a member that's not relevant on your type such as the antiquated [`ICollection.SyncRoot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.syncroot(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Couldn't agree more! The only reason you need to implement explicitly is name clash, but there are architectural reasons that you might want to force someone to make a cast to call. (things are pretty frosty around SO at the moment, how about an up-vote?)

Comment: I hide implementation for convenience of testing and for a possibility of substitution of implementation.